# Align floated divs to fill an entire space

Tags: css, css-float, margin

So I have a div, 720px wide, and i'm filling it with divs that are 140px wide, floated left.  I would love to be able to line these divs up flush with the left and right edges of the containing div.

Of course, the issue is that when I put a margin-right on the floated divs, the right edge won't line up due to that margin.  A left margin yields the same results, but on the left edge.

Is there any way to combat this issue?

Comment: So ... remove the margins? An example (even on jsfiddle) and/or image will go a long way.

Comment: If you're giving it margins, there is no way to flush it to the borders. Unless you position them absolute which will in turn hurt even worst because now they won't float next to each other unless you specify their positions absolutely. I could be wrong, but to my experiences is how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: [Link](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html)

You can put the elements into rows and detect first, middle, and last elements with these css2 selectors. You can specify different margins for the different positions inside.

```
element:first-child {

}

element:last-child {

}

element .className {
     margin-left: 6px;
}
```

Comment: I actually ended up using this: [nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), which I got to from your suggestion.  Wonderful.  It worked out perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a server-side language to generate these divs you can calculate which item is last in the row by doing something like this:

```
<div class="column <%if iteration % 6 == 0 %>last-in-row<%end%>"></div>
```

and then just set the style

```
.column {
   margin-right: 10px;
}
.last-in-row {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```